# How do I get a ListView below (not within) a TabHost in an Android application?

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

Hey, I have a TabHost with two tabs, each with an Activity.

The first is an Activity that has a normal textView.
The second tab is a ListActivity with a ListView.

All this works fine.
However, I want to add another listview BELOW the TabHost.
So Basically I would have:
Tab Buttons
Tab Content (The Activity: Text or List)
ListView

My main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/footerlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, I'm really not sure how to set the data for the footer list.
An activity using a ListView needs to extend ListActivity...
But my main Activity extends TabActivity so I'm not sure how to fill in the list data since I can't use ListAdapter without extending ListActivity.
Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.
I used a `RelativeLayout` instead of `ListLayout`

My final XML (if useful to anyone):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerlist"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/footerlist"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

An activity using a `ListView` can be a simple `Activity`, not only `ListActivity`. So, just add to your xml layout under the `</TabHost>` your `ListView`.    Btw, `TabHost` can be included in an ordinary `Activity` instead of `TabActivity` too.

Comment: How would I get the actual data into the `ListView` from the main activity?

Comment: `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);`  `listView.setAdapter(yourListAdapter);`//or whatever you want to do with your `ListView`

Comment: I have:
`ListView footerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.footerlist);`
`footerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String(this,R.layout.list_item,FOOTER));`

And `static final String[] FOOTER = new String[] {"FooterText"};`

But nothing shows

Comment: That should show "<String>" not "<String" and I mean my Tab and content still show... just not the footer list I want

Comment: Should work :) Mb you missed something or maybe it's specific to tabhost.

Comment: Can you show your final xml with `TabHost` and `ListView`? Maybe you can't see your `ListView` coz of `TabHost`'s layout height set to `fill_parent`? If so, change it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Ok I edited the xml file in the original question to show what I have. If I change `TabHost`'s layout height to `wrap_content` instead of what I posted, I see the footer in the middle of the screen on my first tab because that tab has a `TextView` that only fits half the page. It's not acting like a footer. And on my second tab, it doesn't show at all because that tab's `ListView` fits the whole screen (it even scrolls).

Comment: You forgot to add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the `TabHost` in approach with `LinearLayout`, so `TabHost` would stretch to all screen except that `ListView`